# efficient way to run script in java

Tags: java, shell

I would like to run a shell script(.sh) from a Java class.

Which is the **most efficient and fastest** way to achieve this?

Is it better to run this script directly from Java, using groovy or is there another way?

Comment: About what kind of script we are talking about? Please be more precise about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you talking about a shell script? In That case use `Runtime.exec()` or use `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I assumed he wanted to run a JS script from Java, but perhaps you're right... difficult to tell.

Comment: When i call my java class will be executed this script which will be .sh .This script will make changes in another file(.txt).

Comment: In that case you need to run a Process the way I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a process builder to create and execute your script:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("script.sh", "arg1", "arg2"); //Add more arguments as needed
processBuilder.directory(new File("scriptDir")); //Set the working directory, if needed
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

You could also just fire out a call to `Runtime.exec()`:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script.sh");
```

Personally I'd go with the first approach - it lets you set arguments, working directory, environment variables etc. in a much cleaner and easier way than with just an `exec()` call.

Comment: He has edited the question to make it clear that he is asking about a shell script, not scripting in general.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks, have updated to reflect it.

Comment: It is very important for me to find the most efficient solution. So if my script.sh have to make changes in a huge file.txt which approach will take less time?What about grooby approach?

Comment: There's absolutely no difference. Both the examples I've listed here (and any sensible ones that would be implemented in Groovy) just execute the shell script as a separate process, so the efficiency of the task from Java doesn't really come into it at all.

Comment: So if you run the script directly in your java using ProcessBuilder it will take the same time running this script via groovy??

Comment: @petros_bal If you run it directly from pretty much any language it'll take the same length of time, yes.